# Ruby on Rails 4 - Check whether nested form entries already exist in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an app for a music library that is organized by album and artist. Users can upload music to the server via an album submission form that contains nested attributes for tracks. When an album is uploaded, the app should check whether each track already exists in the database based on its name. If the track does already exist, the association with the album should be mapped to the existing record, and a duplicate of the track should not be made. I have tried to implement this in my `Album` model, where I have the following code:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :get_tracks

  ...

  has_and_belongs_to_many :artists
  has_many :album_tracks,  counter_cache: true
  has_many :tracks, through: :album_tracks

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tracks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :album_tracks, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: lambda {|a| a[:track_number].blank?}

  def get_tracks
    self.tracks = self.tracks.collect do |track|
        track.artists = track.artists.collect do |artist|
            Artist.find_or_create_by(name: artist.name, class_year: artist.class_year)
        end
        Track.create_with(artists: track.artists, audio: track.audio).find_or_create_by(name: track.name)
    end
  end
end
```

This code was working until I changed the relationship between `Album` and `Track` from HABTM to `has_many :through` using an `AlbumTrack` join model, in order to have different track numbers on different albums. Now, when I try to upload an existing track onto a new album, a duplicate entry is formed. I suspect that this problem arises from the differences between the many-to-many relationships, as duplicate artist entries (which are associated by HABTM) are not created.

Is there a workaround to this, or a better approach altogether?

Comment: I would argue that the relationship between track and album should not be HABM. I would treat each track as unique in the scope of an album. Its pretty common that artists release the same songs in slightly varying versions on different albums but they are are actually unique in that they might have different arrangements or length.

Comment: What you're saying makes sense but I'm going to leave this question open because the concept might apply to things that other people are doing.